# JProfiler: How do results from Hibernate profiling and JDBC profiling correlates?

Tags: jprofiler

In JProfiler, how do I correlate the JDBC probe result and Hibernate probe result?

My current assumption is that time values shown in Hibernate probe report relates to the time needed for Hibernate to process HQL/Criteria into SQL **plus** SQL execution time;
While JDBC time is strictly SQL execution time in DB.

Is it a correct assumption?

In the following, the first pic showed that a Criteria (lets call it X) takes the most inherent time.
However, in the second pic we can see that the resulting SQL from Criteria X is only 9th.
This leads me to the assumption above.

[image: JPA/Hibernate profiling report]
[image: JDBC profiling report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The JPA/Hibernate time includes the JDBC execution time.